# Dataset ReadXmlSchema Errors

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, dataset, xmldocument

How is it possible for this to be true

```
XmlDocument d = BuildReportXML(schema);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXmlSchema(schema);
ds.ReadXml(new XmlNodeReader(d));
```

Schema is the schema location that I apply to the XmlDocument before I start setting data, assuring that all the columns are of the correct type. Then I set the schema to the DataSet, and read the document into it. When I do this it throws an "Input string was not in a correct format." I have a few decimal variables in the Xml, and I assume this is the error. All of the information is obviously of the correct format, else the XmlDocument would have had errors. What can I do?

Comment: Some of the answers below have some of the description from MSDN and looking at what went wrong it seems that msreekm is right. Check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx29c3yd.aspx

Answer (score 1):

FxCop recommends always setting the locale of a DataSet. e.g.:

```
ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

Could it be that the locale of your DataSet does not match the Xml you are reading?

Answer (score 1):

Does the XML document contain empty values in the double? This could be an issue!

Also I remember reading about same name used in as root element, element and attribute causing issue.. Not sure if it is fixed in some service pack.. so try making all these names different!